# What can i do to for these stack smashing detected in my program?

Tags: c, stack-smash

I have submitted the code please help me. The program is about creating a string data structure for containing dictionary only for alphabet a.

```
[   #include <stdio.h>
    #include <string.h>
    #include <stdlib.h>
    char *string[1000];
    /*This program is about creating a string data structure 
     *for 'a' alphabet only.
     */
    main()
    {
        char buffer[50];
        int i=0,size = 0;
        FILE *fp = fopen("A_dict.txt","r");
        while(fgets(buffer,1000,fp)!=NULL)
        {
            string[size] = (char *)malloc(strlen(buffer)+1);
            strcpy(string[size],buffer);
            size = size + 1;
        }
            string[size] = NULL;
        printf("the size of string array is %d\n",size);
        printf("The content are:\n");
        for(i = 0; i < size; i++)
        {
            puts(string[i]);
        }
        fclose(fp);
    }]
```

These is the error that I'm getting - 
 
[image]

Comment: You have an array `buffer` of 50 characters, then you allow `fgets` to read up to 999 characters into it? Yes that's definitely going to lead to bad things and undefined behavior if the input is more than 49 characters (including possible newline).

Comment: Stop trying to put 999 characters into a 50 character buffer would be a start. [`man fgets`](https://linux.die.net/man/3/fgets).

Comment: Don't post images of text. And follow [ask].